# TinyMCE Setting focus in text part

Tags: text, tinymce

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="block-container">
   <div id="some-background"></div>
   <div id="text-div">Focus should be here when this HTML goes into the editor</div>
</div>
```

I want the caret be in the text-div -- more precisely in the first text element -- when it opens in the TinyMCE editor.

There could be a way to add some class like ".default-focused" to such element and set focus based on the class. Is there any other (generalized) way to achieve this?

The reason why I can't go with the ".default-focused" way:
1. It could be huge task to add class considering the amount of data I have and
2. More importantly, user can change the HTML and can remove the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you know in which element the caret is to be placed you may use this short function

```
// sets the cursor to the specified element, ed ist the editor instance
// start defines if the cursor is to be set at the start or at the end
setCursor: function (ed, element, start) {

    var doc = ed.getDoc();
    if (typeof doc.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        range.collapse(start);
        var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
        var sel = win.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof doc.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(element);
        textRange.collapse(start);
        textRange.select();
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks. Any other solution, when I don't know the element in which the focus should be set?

Comment: no, but name a scenario in which you are not able to get the element?